# Launch magit directly from ido in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

I want to launch [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) directly from [ido](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings). I.e., I want to launch ido with `ido-find-file`, navigate to the directory where I want to run magit, press some key combination like <kbd>C-x g</kbd>, and have ido quit and and magit open in that directory.

I currently just press <kbd>C-d</kbd> to open dired in the directory, and then press <kbd>C-x g</kbd> to open magit, but I would like to avoid that extra <kbd>C-d</kbd>.

I managed to add a new key-combination to `ido-completion-map`:

```
(add-hook 'ido-minibuffer-setup-hook
          (lambda () (interactive)
            (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-x g") 'arvid-ido-enter-magit-status)
            ))
```

But the following function does not seem to work, just opening dired with instead of magit:

```
(defun arvid-ido-enter-magit-status ()
  "Drop into `dired' from file switching."
  (interactive)
  (setq ido-exit 'dired)
  (magit-status default-directory)
  (exit-minibuffer))
```

Comment: By the way, I recommend you ask Emacs questions here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking Emacs questions here (StackOverflow, tag `emacs`). Either is OK and useful.

Comment: Then what is the point of the emacs stackexchange? Why should one use one over the other?

Comment: @Drew I didn't say otherwise. I just made a recommendation.

Comment: @arvixx On Emacs.Stackexchange everyone is an Emacs user, which at least for question about packages that are not part of Emacs itself, should make it more likely that you get an useful answer. That's especially true for questions about Magit because I (the maintainer) always answer them there (unless someone else already answered), while here I usually only check every few weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magit already comes with such a function:

```
(defun ido-enter-magit-status ()
  "Drop into `magit-status' from file switching.

To make this command available use something like:

  (add-hook 'ido-setup-hook
            (lambda ()
              (define-key ido-completion-map
                (kbd \"C-x g\") 'ido-enter-magit-status)))

Starting with Emacs 25.1 the Ido keymaps are defined just once
instead of every time Ido is invoked, so now you can modify it
like pretty much every other keymap:

  (define-key ido-common-completion-map
    (kbd \"C-x g\") 'ido-enter-magit-status)"
  (interactive)
  (with-no-warnings ; FIXME these are internal variables
    (setq ido-exit 'fallback fallback 'magit-status))
  (exit-minibuffer))
```